# UIStatusBar with UISearchController bug

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using UISearchController when the user select the input textfield the UIStatusBar is no longer transparent and in the back i can see UITableView contents i'm trying several solutions but nothing works

any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I am having the same issue and haven't found a solution just yet. Working on it though. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: It's a bug. See my workaround: stackoverflow.com/a/30225864/235297